S3 with cloud front is not loading Images resulting in 403
I've setup s3 bucket with cloudfront only for images. the web app is still under development and hosted on Cloudways,  I'm currently travelling and in New Delhi, India. I noticed the images are not loading and resulting in 403. But images were loading when I was in Sydney but when in new Delhi when I'm trying to access the staging env the images are not loading and resulting in 403. Also I images are loading in western part of India (Gujrat).
Details of s3
AWS Region
Asia Pacific (Sydney) ap-southeast-2
Policy
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::615232063:distribution/E36UJDYECDFGJC"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}```

